# How to change color of icons in material ui

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

why cant I change color of search icon using sx
I tried changing the color from css using class name(searchIcon) but it does not work.

Tried this, can tell why is sx not working

```
import React from 'react'
import './Header.css'
import SearchIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Search';
import { grey, pink } from '@mui/material/colors';

function Header() {
  return (
    <div className='header'>
      <div className='header__left'>
        <img src="
        https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/logotypes/32/square-linkedin-512.png" 
        alt="" />

        <div className='header__search'>
          <SearchIcon sx={{ color: "grey[100]"}}/>
          <input type='text'/>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className='header__right'></div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Header
```

Comment: You've a typo, `color: "grey[100]"` should be `color: grey[100]`, remove the quotes from around the value. Voting to close as "Not reproducible or was caused by a typo".

Comment: tried but it does not work, even tried <SearchIcon sx={{ color: pink[200] }}/>

Comment: Seems to work just fine for us. Here's a working [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/how-to-change-color-of-icons-in-material-ui-yt8gic) demo.

Comment: thanks for trying but its not working for me in any of my projects, maybe I have a problem in somewhere else

Comment: Sure, that's very likely. As-is, this is an unreproducible problem based on current information. Feel free to fork the sandbox I created and add more of your code to see if you can reproduce the issue that we can then inspect live.

Comment: instead of export default function App() {}
i used export default Header
is this the problem?

Comment: I doubt it. If `Header` is default exported then it needs to be default imported. Whether it's a default export/import or a named export/import won't really change how the MUI imports work and are used. Like I said though, feel free to fork the sandbox and edit to more accurately reflect your actual code to see if you can reproduce the issue. If you can, then we have something to work with.

Comment: I just noticed sx={{backgroundColor: 'white'}} this works but sx={{color: 'white'}} does not work, i did fork and saw the code

Comment: Have you tried making a codesandbox demo that reproduces the issue(s) you are seeing? Since it's working for us it's difficult or impossible for us to say why it's not working as expected for you.

Comment: no i couldnot reproduce it

Answer (score 0):

Remove quotes around the color property and write like this: sx={{ color: grey[100]}}

Comment: tried but it does not work, even tried <SearchIcon sx={{ color: pink[200] }}/>